# nest elasticsearch : how to target multi types in SearchRequest Object?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to do a request on several types with a SearchRequest object

My request would look like to the code bellow:

```
var searchQuery = new BoolQuery
 {
      Should = shouldContainers,
      Filter = filterContainers
 };

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<dynamic>()
{
     //Don't know how to target type
     Type = EType.All,
     //or 
     Type = typeof(obj1) && typeof(obj2)  
     Query = searchQuery,
     Size = size
     From = fromNumber,
     MinScore = 1
};

var response = await client.SearchAsync<dynamic>(searchRequest);
```

Do you know if it is possible to do something like that and how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the index/type in the endpoint, it will search the whole cluster.

Update:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     /_search
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   document:
    //     describes an elasticsearch document of type T, allows implicit conversion from
    //     numeric and string ids
    public SearchRequest();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     /{index}/_search
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   index:
    //     Optional, accepts null
    public SearchRequest(Indices index);

    //
    // Summary:
    //     /{index}/{type}/_search
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   index:
    //     Optional, accepts null
    //
    //   type:
    //     Optional, accepts null
    public SearchRequest(Indices index, Types type);

    // The second one is what you are looking for, query on specific index regardless type, it does `POST /{index}/_search`

    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(myIndex){...} 
    var result = client.Search<dynamic>(searchRequest);
```

Comment: thank you but ip appears to produce a request  : POST: /index/object/_search and it gives me no results

Comment: I have 

`var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(){...}`
`var result = client.Search<dynamic>(searchRequest);`
and I can see the actual request is `POST /_search` which query all indicies and all types

Comment: yes if i write   var searchRequest = new SearchRequest() insteade of var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<dynamic>() , it request on all types!!! :D  thank you.  But unfortunately it also on all indexes (i don't want this) :( :(

Comment: then you can use `var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index){...}`
`// Summary:

        //     /{index}/_search

        //

        // Parameters:

        //   index:

        //     Optional, accepts null

        public SearchRequest(Indices index);`